# I am trying to make a program which allows three inputs and then prints out the biggest one, but the code is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, windows, output

```py
print("this is program is to check which NUMBER you chose is bigger,(NOTE: any input except number input     will break down the program)\n")
a=int(input("first number:")) 
b=int(input("second number:"))
c=int(input("third number:"))
if "a">"b":
    z=a
else:
    z=b
if "z" > "c":
    print(z)
else:
    print(c)
```

my code   ↑
I have tried everything like doing it in notepad & saved it with the extension but I am always get the whatever input is in variable "b"

Comment: you are compering string with each other ' "a" > "b" ', not actual values

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you expecting and getting instead?

Comment: What you probably want is to drop the quotes around `a`, `b`, `z` and `c` in both if statements.

Comment: `"a"` is a string literal. Why are you adding quotation marks? You're not referring to the actual variable names

Comment: thankyou for helping me out I really appreciate it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Your title, in particular, isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, change your variable "a","b" and "z" to a, b and z. "a" is considered as a string instead of being a variable

```
print("this is program is to check which NUMBER you chose is bigger,(NOTE: any input except number input will break down the program)\n")
a=int(input("first number:")) 
b=int(input("second number:"))
c=int(input("third number:"))
if a > b:
    z=a
else:
    z=b
if z > c:
    print(z)
else:
    print(c)
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time to tell me what the problem was

Answer (score -1):

You should not be using " " when you are comparing the numbers.
You can do this instead,

```
a=int(input("first number:")) 
b=int(input("second number:"))
c=int(input("third number:"))
if (a>= b) and (a >= c):
     largest = a
elif (b >= a) and (b >= c):
     largest = b
else:
     largest = c

print("The largest number is", largest)
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time to help me in my coding